# Value is not going in email

Tags: php, javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function show() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block'; }
            function hide() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none'; }
          </script>

    <form action="email.php" name="form" id="form" onSubmit="return check()" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Fname"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="Lname"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="Address"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="City"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="State"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="Zip"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="Email"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="Phone"/><br />

    <input type="radio" name="Donation" value="One Time Annual, Gift of $365.00" onclick="hide();"  />One Time Annual, Gift of $365.00<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Donation" value="Monthly Gift of $30.00" onclick="hide();" />Monthly Gift of $30.00<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Donation" value="Monthly Gift of $30.00" onclick="hide();"  />Monthly Gift of $30.00<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Donation" value="At Least $1 Per Day"  onclick="hide();" />At Least $1 Per Day<br />
    <input type="radio" name="Donation"  onclick="show();" />I would like to give a one time gift of
    <input type="text" id="area" name="Donation" style="display: none;"  />


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action"/>




and in email.php page i use array('First Name','Last Name','Address','City','State','Zip','Email','Phone','Donation')``
```

when i select last radio button then in email value is going but when i use any other radio button then value is not going in email, pls help me...

Comment: my email value is donation,  when i select last radio button and put any value in text box, then value is going fine, but when i select other radio button then value is not going..

Comment: You mean to say, when you click on other radio button your Donation  text box should be empty (no text) which is not working right now ? Is it so ?

Comment: yes, when i will click other radio button then value of that radio button should go in email...

Comment: this is the link ehere i am working http://developer.nextgenexperts.in/donation/index.php

Comment: Oh, it's confusing, just give me one scenario of events in your question that you want, after which button click, which text box value will change.

Comment: please see this link developer.nextgenexperts.in/donation/index.php then u can understand

Answer (score 0):

All radio button has same name, Which is correct. But You have last text field also as same name.Please change text field name from "Donation" to something else and try.

Comment: Hi Biswajit, when i change text field name from "Donation" and when i send email the "Donation: on" is coming in email, so it is not working well..

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block'; }
function hide() {
   document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none';
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('Donation');
    for (var i=0, len=elements.length; i<len; ++i)      {
        if (elements[i].checked)
        document.getElementById('Email').value = elements[i].value;
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id ="Email" name="Email"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last radio button's name, when you click this one, it will show the destination input textfield. This way you won't have a double destination post.